# Expanding dict entries into rows with Pandas

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I'm trying to expand dict keys and values into their own columns using Python3 and Pandas.  Below is an example.  Not all dicts have the same number of items and there's no guarantee that key names match for each metric type.

I want to convert this dataframe:

```
id  metric          dicts
1   some_metric_1   {'a': 161, 'b': 121}
2   some_metric_1   {'a': 152, 'c': 4}
2   some_metric_2   {'b': 162, 'a': 83}
3   some_metric_2   {'b': 103, 'z': 69}
```

Created by this:

```
data = {'id': [1, 2, 2, 3], 'metric': ['some_metric_1', 'some_metric_1', 'some_metric_2', 'some_metric_2'], 'dicts': [{'a': 161, 'b': 121}, {'a': 152, 'c': 4}, {'b': 162, 'a': 83}, {'b': 103, 'z': 69}]}
df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(data)
```

into this:

```
id  metric          key value
1   some_metric_1   a   161
1   some_metric_1   b   121
2   some_metric_1   a   152
2   some_metric_1   c   4
2   some_metric_2   b   162
2   some_metric_2   a   83
3   some_metric_2   b   103
3   some_metric_2   z   69
```

Answer (score 1):

You can simply iterate through the rows of your DataFrame and extract the values needed as shown below.

Now keep in mind that the code below assumes that each key will only have 1 value (i.e. no list of value will be passed to a dict key). Though, it will work regardless of the numbers of keys.

```
final_df = pd.DataFrame()

for row in df.iterrows():
    metric = row[1][1]      # get the value in the metric column
    i = row[1][0]           # get the id value
    for key, value in row[1][2].items():
        tmp_df = pd.DataFrame({
            'id':i,
            'metric':metric,
            'key': key,
            'value': value
        }, index=[0])

        final_df = final_df.append(tmp_df) # append the tmp_df to our final df

final_df.reset_index(drop=True)  # Reset the final DF index sinze we assign index 0 to each tmp df
```

**Output**

```
    id  metric        key   value
0   1   some_metric_1   a   161
1   1   some_metric_1   b   121
2   1   some_metric_1   c   152
3   2   some_metric_1   a   152
4   2   some_metric_1   c   4
5   2   some_metric_2   b   162
6   2   some_metric_2   a   83
7   3   some_metric_3   b   103
8   3   some_metric_3   z   69
```

Here is more information regarding [`df.append()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.append.html).

Answer (score 1):

I find this type of problem easier to solve in plain Python rather than Pandas - once you are storing dictionaries in your DataFrame, it's going to be difficult to perform the kind of fast vectorized operations which make Pandas so useful for simple numeric/string data.

Here's my solution which involves a couple of comprehensions, and `zip`.

```
metrics = df['metric']
dicts = df['dicts']
ids = df['id']
metrics, ids = zip(*((m, i) for m, d, i in zip(metrics, dicts, ids) for j in range(len(d))))
keys, values = zip(*((k, v) for d in dicts for k, v in d.items()))
new_data = {'id': ids, 'metric': metrics, 'keys': keys, 'values': values}
new_df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(new_data)
```

Results:

```
   id keys         metric  values
0   1    a  some_metric_1     161
1   1    b  some_metric_1     121
2   2    a  some_metric_1     152
3   2    c  some_metric_1       4
4   2    b  some_metric_2     162
5   2    a  some_metric_2      83
6   3    b  some_metric_2     103
7   3    z  some_metric_2      69
```